# SharePoint 2013: Programatically Installing AND Activating sandbox solutions using CSOM

Tags: 2013, deployment, sandbox-solution

I have tested this successfully, but wanted to check if anyone else has run into issues with this approach?

The following object `SP.Publishing.DesignPackage` allows you to `.install()` and `.apply()` sandbox solutions as well as design packages.

Example code:

```
private static void ApplyDesign(ClientContext context, string fileUrl)
{
    DesignPackageInfo info = new DesignPackageInfo()
    {
       PackageGuid = Guid.Empty,
       MajorVersion = 1,
       MinorVersion = 1,
       PackageName = "whatever"
    };
    Console.WriteLine("Installing design package / sandbox solution ");

    // have the package in a doc lib or something...
    string fileRelativePath = context.Url + fileUrl;
    DesignPackage.Install(context, context.Site, info, fileRelativePath);
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    Console.WriteLine("Applying Design Package!  / sandbox solution ");
    DesignPackage.Apply(context, context.Site, info);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Source: http://blog.symprogress.com/2013/07/apply-designpackage-using-client-object-model/

Answer (score -1):

I am getting exception on below line

```
DesignPackage.Install(context, context.Site, info, fileRelativePath);
```

Exception : *An exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException' occurred in Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Cannot find stub for type with id "{d21214d9-63f5-488b-a665-2b7f9abc1604}". The specified server may not support APIs used in this operation.*

I am trying to install sandbox wsp on site collection in SharePoint Foundation.
Can you please help?